# How to return boolean value in ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, repository

The controller code is given below:

```
@PutMapping("/update-student")
public ResponseEntity<Student>updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student)throws Exception{
  boolean getStudent = studentService.updateStudent(student);
  return new ResponseEntity<Student>(getStudent,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: What is your use case for returning boolean? If you want to return `false` if student's save/updation has failed, you are better of returning an error code.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `ResponseEntity` of type `Student` (`ResponseEntity<Student>`)

To return Boolen you would have to do something like 
`ResponseEntity<Boolean>`.